# how do you increase the height of an html textbox

Tags: html, textbox

How do you increase the height of an textbox? (along with its font size)

Comment: you shouldn't use explicit pt or px measurements for css, you should always use ems for increased accessibility.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, height does not work :( http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/Eknsc it's because of search, I'll post a new question tomorrow

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I'm assuming from the way you worded the question that you want to change the size after the page has rendered?

In Javascript, you can manipulate [DOM CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSS), for example:

```
document.getElementById('textboxid').style.height="200px";
document.getElementById('textboxid').style.fontSize="14pt";
```

If you simply want to specify the height and font size, use CSS or style attributes, e.g.

```
//in your CSS file or <style> tag
#textboxid
{
    height:200px;
    font-size:14pt;
}

<!--in your HTML-->
<input id="textboxid" ...>
```

Or

```
<input style="height:200px;font-size:14pt;" .....>
```

Answer (score 37):

Note that if you want a multi line text box you have to use a `<textarea>` instead of an `<input type="text">`.

Answer (score 11):

Increasing the font size on a text box will usually expand its size automatically.

```
<input type="text" style="font-size:16pt;">
```

If you want to set a height that is not proportional to the font size, I would recommend using something like the following. This prevents browsers like IE from rendering the text inside at the top rather than vertically centered.

```
.form-text{
    padding:15px 0;
}
```

Comment: Good point, due to the question I was assuming he wanted to set both, however if it is just to increase the size of the textbox to fit the large text then this would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="text" style="font-size:xxpt;height:xxpx">
```

Just replace "xx" with whatever values you wish.

Comment: this makes the text render from  vertical center of the text box , how to avoid this?

Answer (score 5):

- With inline style:

  ```
  <input type="text" style="font-size: 18pt; height: 40px; width:280px; ">
  ```
- or with apart CSS:

  HTML:

  ```
  <input type="text" id="txtbox">
  ```

  CSS:

  ```css
  #txtbox {
      font-size: 18pt;
      height: 42px;
      width : 300px;
  }
  ```

Comment: When you post code examples, also post explanations for them.

Answer (score 4):

If you want multiple lines consider this:

```
<textarea rows="2"></textarea>
```

Specify rows as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't the [`height`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/height) and [`font-size`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/font-size) CSS properties work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.Large
{
    font-size: 16pt;
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
<body>
<input type="text" class="Large">
</body>
</html>
```