# How to increase the size of my textbox with input?

Tags: html, input, textbox

I have an html textbox that looks like this:

```
 <div class="control-group">
     <label class="required">
         Enter stuff here
     </label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Required Field" class="form-control" id="secid">
</div>
```

I do further processing on the 'secid' in the javascript file associated with the html file.
I need to increase the size of the textbox on-the-fly i.e. The more text I write, the input textbox gets bigger. There are questions related to this already such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234770/increase-textbox-size-with-text) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152840/how-do-you-increase-the-height-of-an-html-textbox) but none very clear. Could you help me it?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/eVd9b/5/ and http://jsfiddle.net/5QcQK/2/

Comment: jQuery autogrow plugin FTW!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931207/is-there-a-jquery-autogrow-plugin-for-text-fields

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <input  size="5" style="font-family:Courier"; onkeyup="Expand(this);">

 function Expand(obj){
  if (!obj.savesize) obj.savesize=obj.size;
  obj.size=Math.max(obj.savesize,obj.value.length);
 }
```

this will increase and decrease textbox size on change.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eVd9b/54/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<input id="Test" size="2" type="text" onkeyup="Expand(this)"/>
```

And JavaScript as

```
function Expand(obj) {
  obj.size = parseInt(obj.value.length);
}
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x5wenojt/)***